How to estimate weekly mean while preserving rows with NA's
I have a dataset with many weeks of data. However, some days were not sampled and
therefore R generated NA's for those days. I am trying to get the mean per week based
on the sampled days each week. For example, wk 1 was sampled only 3 days so I get
the weekly mean by doing the following:
#Data
  a <- structure(list(wk = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), month = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xd = c(0.0370098838217444, 0.0391215970961887, 
0.0409865246890313, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.015188, 0.007513, 0.012716, 
0.013962, 0.014259, 0.023553, 0.032122, 0.03953, 0.028946, 0.030769, 
0.030815, 0.029187, 0.022604, 0.02892, 0.031055, 0.041924, 0.038164, 
0.044705, NA, NA, NA), td = c(0.02701157274146, 0.0284158620689655, 
0.0296560389182058, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0125, 0.007396, 0.010856, 
0.011685, 0.011882, 0.018063, 0.023761, 0.028687, 0.021649, 0.022861, 
0.022892, 0.021809, 0.017432, 0.021632, 0.023052, 0.030279, 0.027779, 
0.032129, NA, NA, NA), pd = c(317.308439683869, 0, 126.719553152898, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2671.6, 3540.6976744186, 1270.35740604274, 1067.69362430466, 
688.099646524154, 317.444499806234, 420.941879550524, 280.475476696762, 
250.681324772507, 159.048160622895, 258.125109208457, 450.868907331836, 
0, 120.83949704142, 244.794377928162, 0, 226.610029158717, 0, 
NA, NA, NA), year = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))

library(tidyverse)
 a <- a %>% group_by(wk) %>% mutate(wk_days = length(wk))
 a
 
 #I want to get the mean of pd by week which is 148 for wk 1 but after I na.omit()
 # I am left with only the sampled pd days. How Do I create another column with
 #a full week of all the mean values which is 148. The avg column has only 3 148 values
 #but I would like to have all the 7 days of the week with values of 148. The same thing
 #with wk 4, it has only 4 values of 117 but would like to see 7 days of 117 values.
  
a <- a %>% group_by(wk_days, year, month, wk) %>% na.omit() %>%
reframe(avg = mean(pd), summed_avg = avg*wk_days) %>% arrange(wk) %>%
data.frame()
a 

   wk_days year month wk       avg summed_avg
1        7 2007     1  1  148.0093  1036.0653
2        7 2007     1  1  148.0093  1036.0653
3        7 2007     1  1  148.0093  1036.0653
4        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
5        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
6        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
7        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
8        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
9        7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
10       7 2007     1  2 1425.2621  9976.8347
11       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
12       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
13       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
14       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
15       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
16       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
17       7 2007     1  3  217.1484  1520.0385
18       7 2007     1  4  117.8511   824.9577
19       7 2007     1  4  117.8511   824.9577
20       7 2007     1  4  117.8511   824.9577
21       7 2007     1  4  117.8511   824.9577


Why not just omit the NA in the mean() function? ... avg = mean(pd, na.rm=TRUE)

I could but how do I end up with avg 7 times instead of 3 for week 1?

Remove the na.omit

I worked. Is unbelievable that I missed that. Thanks @Edward!!!
